# Determine whether Python code is running in an embedded interpreter

Tags: python, c++, global-variables

I'm writing a c++ application that embeds a Python interpreter. I'd like to install a custom `sys.excepthook` if the code is being run from the embedded interpreter, but not when the code is run from the console.

Looking through the Python C API docs, I came across [PyEval_GetGlobals()](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/reflection.html#c.PyEval_GetGlobals) which I thought I might be able to use to obtain a reference to the `globals` dictionary and set a global variable when initialising the embedded interpreter.

> `PyObject* PyEval_GetGlobals()` 
>   *Return value: Borrowed reference. Return a dictionary of the global
>   variables in the current execution frame, or NULL if no frame is
>   currently executing.*

Unfortunately, this function returns `NULL` because there is no execution frame. Is there any other way to insert a global variable from the C API? Or maybe a better way to determine how the code is being executed from the Python side?